# Need some help for MQTT communcation between android device( Android pie) and server on Google cloud plateform

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi

I need some help for MQTT communication between the android device( Android pie) and server on Google cloud platform. I have gone through Google cloud IOT core that has MQTT broker that communicate with Android things for that supported Hardware is Rasberry Pi. For Android device which broker/way can use for MQTT communication to the server on google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

For android, you can use  *org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3* or *org.eclipse.paho.android.service* to connect to the broker to which your other clients are connected. There might be other java client library available in mvnrepository. I think these are the most popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend you to use Google Firebase if you're designing the system. It has better implementation with Adroid applications and Google Cloud aswell